# Authentication required for Solr 4.10.3 Kerberos

Tags: java, solr, kerberos, solrj, cloudera-cdh

We are using Solr 4.10.3 in Cloudera for data storage. For making queries through java, we use Solrj version 4.10.3-cdh5.4.7. We are referring to this code from solrj wiki documentation:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "<jaas-client.conf path>");
HttpClientUtil.setConfigurer(new Krb5HttpClientConfigurer());
```

and connecting to Solr Cloud (configured with zookeeper) like:

```
CloudSolrServer solr = new CloudSolrServer("<zookeeper_url>");
solr.connect();
```

We are getting "Authentication required" error while running sample queries.

Need help to solve this issue!

Comment: Stop whining, enable the JAAS and Kerberos debug traces i.e. `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` `-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true` `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext` and **check that your JAAS conf is valid**.

Comment: Stopped whining! Still getting same error and yes JAAS config is valid. It shows expected mime type octate/tream but received text/html with full collection path like http://<solr_host>/solr/<collection_wit_shards_and_replica>

Comment: To make things clear: the HTTP query has status OK (200) but an unexpected payload, then the Java code throws an exception that wrongly states it's an auth issue? Or the HTTP query returns an error (401, 403) with some details in HTTP format, and Java correctly reports it's an auth issue?

Comment: @AkashShinde did you ever manage to fix this?